# How to see my pending edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

**Is there a way so I can view my own pending edits?**

extra: If the site merges some consecutive edits, will I and my reviewers see the merges the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Your [suggested edits](https://superuser.com/users/129520/naxa?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) are shown on your profile, but it doesn’t distinguish between accepted, pending, and rejected edits.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your [Profile » Activity » Suggestions](https://superuser.com/users/129520/naxa?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). You will get a list of suggestions — not the pending ones, though, just all in a giant list.

(Shameless self-promotion: Vote for [feature request #2 here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) to have this implemented.)

> If the site merges some consecutive edits …

Edits aren't merged, really. Consecutive edits within a window of five minutes after the last edit (or first revision) are just shown as the last one.

> … will I and my reviewers see the merges the same way?

Yes, there is really no difference between how the author of an edit and other users see it. The only exception is the actual preview of a post. When you submit an edit, the post will have a banner telling you that the edit waits for approval, while other users still see the original revision.